# cv_bridge Package Downloaded, Still Getting Error in ROS Setup

Tags: ros, cv-bridge, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Error:
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "cv_bridge" with
any of the following names:

```
cv_bridgeConfig.cmake
cv_bridge-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "cv_bridge" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"cv_bridge_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"cv_bridge" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351119/i%27ve-downloaded-the-cv_bridge-package-from-the-link-provided-(-https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/tree/kinetic-)-and-pasted-the-cv_bridge-folder-in-the-src-directory.-i%27m-still-getting-the-error-mentioned-in-the-description./) by [Rijul](https://answers.ros.org/users/54219/rijul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-05-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rijul](https://answers.ros.org/users/54219/rijul/) on 2020-05-01**:
Any sort of help or suggestion would be highly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you completed the 4th step here?

http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages

You need to add cv_bridge package to your CMakelists.txt and package.xml files.
I would also recommend you to follow this tutorial, you can see how to create a package by adding cv_bridge as a dependency.

http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [rosberrypi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31252/rosberrypi/) with karma: 75 on 2020-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0